# Early stopping for F-score

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, validation

I'm working on a Relation Extraction Task that has Train/Dev/Test Dataset. The performance is measured by F-score (MicroAverage without Non-entity-relation class). I'm computing a Neural Network for this end, and I have to find the best epoch via early stopping criterion in the Dev set for training a good model. I see in many works that are computed by loss or accuracy independently, but in this task accuracy is not a good metric.

My question is, which is the best metric to find the optimal epoch, the error computed by the loss function, the accuracy or directly the F-measure?

Comment: Which measure you care most for the final performance? Probably should be the choice.

Comment: As I said, the performance is measured by F-score. However, the Neural Network try to decrease the loss and that is how it learns. In that sense, I don't know what is better, the final measure or a good Neural Network that minimize the losses...

Comment: Neural network optimise those loss because it is easy to implement or it can be seen as a convex surrogate of some measure (eg accuracy). You probably cannot easily change that. But you can still control the final performance by using the measure you care most in early stopping or model selection.